# Error message points to the old file structure when I type 'java' at the cmd prompt; CLASSPATH is updated

Tags: classpath

After I re-named my JDK folder and deleted a JRE folder (I actually had to kill a process in order to delete the folder)  then I edited the system variables accordingly but I'm getting error messages when I type in 'javac' or 'java' even when %classpath% shows the updated values.

Is there a hidden system variable that is still holding the older value? How can folder I get ride of the old pointer to jre folder? Is this because I ended a java process earlier in order to be able to delete the JRE folder? If so, how can I fix it now?

Thank you so much in advance for helping me out.

**This is copied from the command window:**

C:\jdk1.7>java

Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

C:\jdk1.7>javac

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\jdk1.7>echo %classpath%
.;C:\jdk1.7\bin;C:\jdk1.7\lib;C:\jdk1.7\jre\bin;C:\ANT\lib;C:\ANT\bin;c:\documen
ts and settings\homayoon\my documents\selenium tutorial\;

C:\jdk1.7>

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed the folder manually, there will be a lot of registry entries that point to the old name.
Change them with RegEdit; or, faster, reinstall Java.